# MOVIMIENTOS DE DATOS EN ASM

Tags: assembly, asm

Hola estoy aprendiendo asm y veo una indicaciones de movimiento para tipo punto flotante, tengo la siguiente duda

```
    movss xmm0, [a]     <--- en este caso estoy moviendo el la variable a a xmm0?
    movsd [b], xmm1     <--- aqui estoy moviendo xmm1 a la variable b?
    movss xmm2, xmm0    <--- aqui un el contenido de un registro reemplaza a otro?
```

soy principiante ayúdenme porfa, muchas gracias